Vite Vue Npm link exports{*/dist} How to fix "Failed to resolve"
How to fix "Failed to resolve"?
If you have a Vue3 app that uses local packages imported via npm link with symbolic links, and you encounter the following error:
12:29:14 PM [vite] Pre-transform error: Failed to resolve import "my-package/socket" from "src/main.ts". Does the file exist?

or
Error: The following dependencies are imported but could not be resolved:

  my-package/socket (imported by 

And the package files in the package.json exports look like:
{
"name": "my-package",
"exports": {
    "./*": {
      "types": "./dist/*.d.ts",
      "default": "./dist/*.js"
    }
  }
}

Workaround Solution
vite.config.ts
// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  ...
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      'my-package': fileURLToPath(new URL('node_modules/my-package/dist', import.meta.url)),
      ...
  }
})



Self-answers are welcome on SO, but please, follow the same rules as other users would. The question shouldn't be made for your own answer and needs to conform https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask , and the answer needs to be posted as such and preferably explain the solution. Here it's unclear why you'd need such a workaround, considering that package.json looks legit and doesn't need a fix, and my-package is your package you could fix it if you had to

@EstusFlask Because it throws an exception as described above, if there is a better solution, I would be happy to use it.

This requires a way to reproduce. The problem is there's no such problem, my-package looks ok. You could add "./socket" entry to exports but I'm unaware of the conditions under which it could be necessary.  I've seen some bugs from Vite where it accidentally failed to resolve the packages it was supposed to, but then they went away and never appeared, probably there was a problem with Vite cache

Yes, you were right. I created a simple version, and it works perfectly. I dug deep into my code and found that I had another wrong export in the package exports, which was breaking the resolution. Now, it works as it's supposed to. Thank you!

Glad you sorted this out
